# Jquery AJAX form with 2 types of data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, canvas

I am trying to send both a simple array and a `canvas.toDataURL()` parameter through one ajax request. The array is being send just fine, but the canvas data isn't. However, if I remove the array 'formData' from being sent the canvas data passes just fine. Thank you for any help. This is my code for the sending the data:

```
var formData = {
        'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
         'age'              : $('input[name=age]').val(),
          'gender'            :  $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(),
          'type'              : $('input[name=type]').val(),  
};

event.preventDefault(); 

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "petupload.php",
    data: { image: canvas.toDataURL(), stuff: formData }
})
```

This is the code for receiving the data(petupload.php):

```
 <?php
 include('include/session.php');

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

  $array=$_POST['stuff']; // Fetching Values from URL
  $image = $_POST['image'];
  $name = $array['name'];
  $age = $array['age'];
  $gender = $array['gender'];
  $type = $array['type'];

 // image name  
$length = 10;
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$imgname = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $imgname .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
 }
 // location to save cropped image
 $url = 'pictures/'.$imgname.'.jpg';

// remove the base64 part
$base64 = preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $_POST['image']);
$base64 = base64_decode($base64);

$source = imagecreatefromstring($base64); // create

imagejpeg($source, $url, 100); // save image

$session->editpet($name, $gender, $type, $age);
$session->profilepic($imgname.'.jpg');

// return URL
$validation = array (
    'url'     => $url . '?' . sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true))
);
echo json_encode($validation);
}
```

Comment: Trailing comma in the formData?

Comment: The trailing comma I did by accident before copying the code, thank you though, and Musa what you said before you deleted it worked just fine, thanks a lot! You should re-post it so people in the future can know if they have this sort of problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the image to the form data as you construct it.

```
var formData = {
    'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
    'age': $('input[name=age]').val(),
    'gender':  $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(),
    'type': $('input[name=type]').val(),  
    'image': canvas.toDataURL()
};
```